# Get the value on button click using jquery with pagination

Tags: php, jquery, datatable

```
$("button").click(function () {
            var base_url = $('#base_url').val();
            var id = $(this).attr('value');
            $('#foo').remove();
            alert(id)
            $.ajax({
                url: base_url + 'Reports/view_extra',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    id: id
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    $("<div id='foo'></div>").appendTo(".append").append(data);
                    $("#dialog-modal").dialog({
                        height: 200,
                        width: 790,
                        modal: true
                    });
                    $("#dialog-modal").css("display", "block");
                    $("#dialog-modal").show();
                }
            });
        });

<td><?php echo isset($v->comments) ? substr(ucfirst($v->comments), 0,100)."... <button class='more' value='$v->fid'>See More</button>" : '-' ?></td>
```

Here is the code.
My Question is when i click on See More button then get the value for me for 10 records. 
But when i used pagination(Datatables) then for other records didn't fetch the value on "See more" button click.

Comment: what happens when you click "See more"  ? Are you getting any js errors or Is it back end issue ?

Comment: Utkarsh - I didn't see any error on console screen and as well in backend.

Comment: click event  not bind  new button form pagination ajax, put event in loaded callback,,or use jquery live

Comment: JOE LEE - Awesome .... Thanx for the good suggestion